# Mysql build query with multiple constraints

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set up a query that outputs the 5 most read articles over the last 4hrs. However, if there are no new articles over the last 4hrs, the list will be empty. What I would like is a query that outputs 5 articles over the last 4hrs. If there are no 5 articles in the last 4hrs, but lets say only 2, I would like to add 3 more newest articles to the list (sorted by log_time). 
So the query should always output 5 articles.
I am wondering if this can be done in one query.

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM feeds where category like '$category' AND log_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR ORDER BY feed_hits DESC LIMIT 5"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error()); 
While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $fid1 = $row["id"];
    $feed_id1 = $row["feed_id"];
    $link1 = $row["link"];
    $title1 = $row["title"];
    $output .= '<a href="detail/' . $fid1 . '" title="' . $title1 . '">' . $title1 . '</a><br/>';
    } 
    mysqli_free_result($query); 
echo $output;
```

Comment: *would like to add 3 more newest articles* how ?? why ??

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via a `UNION` query.  The first half of the below query is simply your original query, which may return up to 5 matching records.  The second half of the query returns an arbitrary number of records which are older than 4 hours.  The entire query is then ordered by log time, with a limit of 5.  This puts your recent target records first, with the older records taking any available positions should they be needed.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM feeds
 WHERE category like '$category' AND log_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR
 ORDER BY feed_hits DESC LIMIT 5) t1

UNION ALL

(SELECT * FROM feeds
 WHERE category like '$category' AND log_time <= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR) t2
ORDER BY log_time DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, this absolutely helped put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You could not limit for 4 HOUR and order by log_time limit 5

```
  "SELECT * 
  FROM feeds 
  where category like '$category' 
  ORDER BY  log_time DESC LIMIT 5";
```

and if you need  ordered  by feed_hits you can reorder the result set

```
  "select * from ( SELECT * 
  FROM feeds 
  where category like '$category' 
  ORDER BY  log_time DESC LIMIT 5 ) t order by feed_hits ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the time filtering and instead order by time, this will always give you the latest:

```
SELECT * FROM feeds WHERE category LIKE '$category' ORDER BY log_time DESC, feed_hits DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Suppose there are 5 matching records within the last 4 hours, but they are not also the 5 latest.  Then your query would not return the intended results (I think).

Comment: Tim's right, I needed to have the top hits over the last 4 hours, added with the latest articles, totaling 5 articles. Quite tricky, but in the end Tim's solution worked.